# sanitize POST arrays

Tags: database, array

I'm trying to sanitize some arrays received through $_POST[] and insert them into database. How should I do that?

The html is name="room_types[]"

$room_types          =      $_POST['room_types'];

how to sanitize this array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_map` like this:

```
$room_types = isset( $_POST['room_types'] ) ? (array) $_POST['room_types'] : array();

$room_types = array_map( 'esc_attr', $room_types ); // Replace esc_attr with your desire sanitization
```